# Helm If / else with conditional value if exists

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have a values file that contains the following key / value pairs:

```
domains:
  - name: "one.dev.beta.com"
  - name: "two.dev.beta.com"
  - name: "three.dev.beta.com"
  - name: "four.dev.beta.com" 
    wwwRedirect: true
```

And a helm chart that I need to conditionalize the behavior for if `wwwRedirect` is `true`. I am new to writing conditionals in GO in helm charts, and wanted to validate this would work. I wanted to know if there was a way to test this behavior as well before deploying my service as well to my cluster:

```
{{ range .Values.domains }}
---
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: {{ .name }}
  namespace: {{ $.Release.Namespace }}
spec:
  secretName: {{ .name }}
  duration: 2h
  renewBefore: 2h
  subject:
    organizations:
    - dev
  isCA: false
  privateKey:
    algorithm: RSA
    encoding: PKCS1
    size: 2048
  commonName: {{ .name }}
  dnsNames:
  {{ if not .name.wwwRedirect }}
    - "{{ .name }}"
    - "www.{{ .name }}"
  {{ else }}
    - "{{ .name }}"
  {{ end }}    
  issuerRef:
    name: letsencrypt-http01-traefik
    kind: ClusterIssuer
{{ end }}
```

The specific part I want to validate is here:

```
  dnsNames:
  {{ if not .name.wwwRedirect }}
    - "{{ .name }}"
    - "www.{{ .name }}"
  {{ else }}
    - "{{ .name }}"
  {{ end }}
```

My assumption on reading this is that if .name.wwwRedirect is not true or doesn't exist, then it would apply dns names with and without www to the list. If name.Redirect is true, then it would just apply it to the name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[helm Debugging Templates](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/debugging/)

`helm template --debug test .`

It's a great way to have the server render your templates, then return the resulting manifest file.